# Result of "a is a is a" comparison

Tags: python

```
A = 314

if A == A == A:
    print('True #1')

if A == A == 271:
    print('True #2')

lie = 0
if lie is lie is lie:
    print('no matter how white, how small,')
    print('how incorporating of a smidgeon')
    print('of truth there be in it.')
```

Result:

```
True #1
no matter how white, how small,
how incorporating of a smidgeon
of truth there be in it.
```

I know it is not normal to use two "="s and "is"s in the if sentence. But I would like to know how the Python interpreter intereprets the `if` statement.

Is the expression `lie is lie is lie` interpreted simultaneously, or short-circuit way?

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneously"? I'm guessing it's being interpreted like `0 < x < 3` just with different operators (and operands).

Comment: Interesting question, but almost certainly a dupe, operator chaining must have been asked before on SO.

Comment: @tripleee By non "simultaneously", I mean "lie is lie" return "True", then "True is lie", whichi may fail. According to replies, I understand that it is interpreted as "lie is lie and lie is lie".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you've happened across is called *operator chaining*.

From the documentation on [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., **`x < y <= z` is
>   equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`**, except that `y` is evaluated only once
>   (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be
>   false).

Emphasis mine.

So, this would mean `lie is lie is lie` is interpreted as `(lie is lie) and (lie is lie)`, and nothing more.

More generally, `a op b op c op d ...` is evaluated the same as `a op b and b op c and c op d ...` and so on. The expression is parsed according to python's [grammar rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). In particular;

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

Answer (score 7):

This question has many answers already, but consider the function split into bytecode:

```
def f():
    lie = 0
    if lie is lie is lie:
        print('Lie')

dis.dis(f)

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (lie)
  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (lie)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (lie)
              8 DUP_TOP
             10 ROT_THREE
             12 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             14 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    22
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (lie)
             18 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             20 JUMP_FORWARD             4 (to 26)
        >>   22 ROT_TWO
             24 POP_TOP
        >>   26 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       36
  4          28 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             30 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Lie')
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             34 POP_TOP
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

This suggests that all `lie`s are being checked to see if they match, in a linear fashion. If one fails, it should break/return.

To confirm, consider:

```
>lie is lie is lie is lie is lie 
True
>lie is not lie is lie is lie is lie is lie
False
>lie is lie is lie is lie is lie is not lie
False
```

Comment: I haven't tried reading the bytecode before. It is useful to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

It will be interpreted as:

```
lie = 0
if lie is lie and lie is lie:
    ...
```

Comment: ... except the third `lie` will not be evaluated a second time.

Comment: Or maybe `lie0 = lie1 = lie2 = 0; if lie0 is lie1 and lie1 is lie2` to slightly clarify which is which.