# Unexpected behavior of relational operators

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Consider `a = 3`.
Now, why is the result of the expression `a == 3 > 1` True ?

It should be equivalent to either `(a == 3) > 1` or `a == (3 > 1)`. Both these expressions are `False` . Then why is the first one True ?

Comment: This is called "operator chaining". See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315871/4909087)

Comment: Here we have 'operator chaining'.  
Look the operation as: '(3==3) and (3>1)',which equals True and True , hence output is True.  
First interpreter is comparing (3==3) which is True then it is comparing (3>1) which is also True. Hence the output is True.  

Operator chaining in one sentence is: if any operation in chain return False then the output is False else it is True.